# Как вывести данные php в html таблицу при помощи AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день господа, есть готовый код написанный на php, который выводит данные в html таблицу:

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($data as $values): ?>
                    <?php $hyperkey = $values['list_project_id']; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($values as $value) : ?>
                            <td><a href="/project/<?= $hyperkey ?>"><?= $value ?></a></td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Я хочу при клике button обновлять свою таблицу, и AJAX самое лучшее решение.
Начал я так:

```
function fucnSuccess(data){
        $('tbody').html(data)
}
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#reload").click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "server.php",
                            success: fucnSuccess
                        })
                    }); 
                });`
```

Начало вроде понятное, цепляем на button наш AJAX, Но что делать с php данными, переводить в JSON? Как это реализовать?
И как быть если нужно обновить данные в двух страницах, т.е таблица такая, когда я нажимаю на запись - она подгружает информацию (так же из Mysql) об это записи

Comment: По простому можно js оставить как есть, а запрос делать на тот-же php,  где будет сгенерированный html

Comment: по подробней можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перенести всю логику отрисовки html на js, то это примерно так:

php:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

js/jQuery:

```
function fucnSuccess(data) {
    var rows = '';
    for (var i in data) {
        var hyperkey = data[i].list_project_id;
        var row = '<tr>';
        for (var v in data[i]) {
            row += '<td><a href="/project/' + hyperkey + '">' + data[i][v] + '</a></td>';
        }
        row += '</tr>'
        rows += row;
    }
    $('tbody').html(rows)
}
```

А можно оставить ваш php как есть, делать запрос к тому-же php на котором находимся и обновлять таблицу так:

```
function fucnSuccess(data){
    var tmp = $('<tmp>').html(data);
    $('tbody').html(tmp.find('tbody').html());
}
```

Comment: т.е если вариант с php, то мне надо "всю логику отрисовки"  перекинуть туда где я обращался к бд и формировал запросы, а вывод сделать как return $myTBODY

Comment: я предложил вариант чтобы вообще не трогать существующий php, просто дергать всю страницу заново и на клиенте обновлять только содержимое tbody

Comment: я понял вас про обновление, но что будет в "data" я так и не понял.

Comment: в data будет весь html страницы

Comment: при  добавление записи в саму таблицу html нужно использовать метод append.